# Is React Native's LayoutAnimation supported on Android?

Tags: react-native

I do not see [anything in the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation.html) referring to lack of support for Android.  I'm using a simple preset animation:

`LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);`

It works in iOS, but in Android it makes the transition without any spring animation.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As per [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#layoutanimation) for Android support you have to add these lines:

```
 import  {
   UIManager,
   LayoutAnimation
 } from 'react-native';

 //..

 UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental && UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
```

Comment: Nice!  I didn't see that because they put it under the Animations page but not the LayoutAnimation page!

Comment: @nomad right , glad if it helps. Note that also need to import the `UIManager` from `react-native` , i added it to my answer

Comment: Does this affects anything on IOs or it is simple ignored?

Comment: This makes  view go disappear for some reason

Answer (score 17):

First import the following:

```
 import  {
   UIManager,
   LayoutAnimation, Platform
 } from 'raect-native';
```

then in component class :

```
   constructor() {
    super();
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental && UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
    }
}
```

This is how it worked for me .

Answer (score 3):

writing both below lines work for my android htc desire pro 10

```
LayoutAnimation.spring();

UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental && UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it like below.
call imports **UIManager**,**LayoutAnimation**.
like this:

```
import {
  Text,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
  UIManager,
  LayoutAnimation
} from 'react-native';
```

then in constructor...add these two lines code...

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
      UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
  }
```