# React Native LayoutAnimation scrollView container size

Tags: animation, react-native, layout-animation

I have some components wrapped in a ScrollView and for some condition the bottom most component shouldn't render. When that happens, I use LayoutAnimation to hide it. The problem is that when the component disappear, the ScrollView jumps to the new content height directly, without any animation at all.
I want to use LayoutAnimation since I have screens where the contents height is unknown.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8E9X.png)

If you look at the image, when the button is pressed, the screen will instantly jump to the blue box without any animation.

```
state = { showGreenBox: false };

  renderBottomBox() {
    if (this.state.showGreenBox) {
      return (
        <View style={{ height: 300, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ height: 300, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
        <View style={{ height: 300, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'blue' }} />
        {this.renderBottomBox()}

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
            this.setState({ showGreenBox: !this.state.showGreenBox });
          }}
        >
          <Text>Press to collapse green box</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I copy-paste your code and it gives me perfect animation ...

Comment: Use 'setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental' for android try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357368/is-react-natives-layoutanimation-supported-on-android

Comment: @K.Wu Did you first scroll down to the bottom most of the screen and then pressed the button so that the green box disappeared? Are you on android or iOS?

Comment: @PTT I'm using iOS. Should have mentioned.

Comment: @Jaros have u found a solution to this ?